# NSStream, sending/receiving data

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstream

I've written a server with Python (Twisted) and now want to connect it with iOS, but having some trouble.

This is how I connect to the server:

```
CFStreamCreatePairWithSocketToHost(NULL, (CFStringRef)@"localhost", 3000, &readStream, &writeStream);
inputStream = (NSInputStream *)readStream;
outputStream = (NSOutputStream *)writeStream;
[inputStream setDelegate:self];
[outputStream setDelegate:self];
[inputStream scheduleInRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
[outputStream scheduleInRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
[inputStream open];
[outputStream open];
```

The problem comes with the RunLoop. Imagine that I wan't to send to the server one message. Then I would do:

```
NSData *data = [[NSData alloc] initWithData:[message dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding]];
[outputStream write:[data bytes] maxLength:[data length]];
```

BUT what if I wan't to send TWO messages, one after the other? Then I could run the code with message1 and message2... but then what the client really sends is a concatenation of message1+message2, not two different messages. I guess this is because I write the messages to the outputStream in the same "loop", so when the stream finally decides to send the data, it sends both... I can't figure out any solution. The same happens if SERVER sends more than one message to CLIENT "very fast". What should I do?

Comment: is there any flush method that you could call?

Comment: @NicolasManzini I don't think so... I've search in Google and found nothing. I'm new to servers, tcp, streams...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define the "protocol" - basically a "grammar" which defines the "language" which will be understood by the participants.

The simplest approach would be to define tokens and separators and a corresponding parser.

For example you might define a *message* consisting of a single char, and multiple messages will be separated by one or more spaces. Then you can send this over the wire:

A B C D E

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The actual protocol is something like command/data, I guess I could do something like cmd1/data1_cmd2/data2, ... the problem here is that when the SERVER sends to CLIENT some data it has a 1024B buffer... I know that separated "packets" (cmd/data) won't take more than 1024Bytes, but if more than one is sent... Also, I'm afraid that maybe if SERVER sends X Bytes the CLIENT may receive in a first "runLoop" Y bytes, and the rest (X-Y) Bytes in the next loop.

Comment: Absolutely. Thus, you need to accumulate the received bytes in some sufficiently large "command buffer" until you get a complete command, and the same for "parameters" aka data.

Comment: OK! I'll give it a try. I thought that maybe there was a kind of "elegant" solution. Thanks!